# What is the differnce between cat test and cat < test?

Tags: linux, cat

What does the `<` symbol mean and when should I use it?

I understand `>` and `>>`.

Also, are there any other symbols like this?

Comment: `man bash` is a long but interesting read.

Comment: "cat test" will print on shell what's written in the test file, if it exists. The command < file means that the input for the command will be read from the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases the result will be the same. The difference is:

- with `cat test` you tell the `cat` program to open the file itself
- with `cat < test` you tell the shell to open the file and feed it to `cat`

You could notice a difference in behavior for example when running a program with superuser priviledges. If your regular user can't access `test` file but superuser can, than:

- `sudo cat test` will be able to print the file
- `sudo cat < test` will not

This is because `sudo` causes `cat` to be run as superuser, but doesn't affect the shell's priviledges, so depending on whether `cat` or the shell is opening the file, this operation will succeed or fail.